# In scrapy how do I yield additional values from a json file along with scraped items to pass to pipelines

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy

In my spider file I am trying to pass additional items from my json file to my pipelines file so that they can be included in a DB insert or update. How do I do that? What would be the correct way to do this?

In the spider I have two for loops but I know this isnt correct. The goal is in the piplines file to do a select from the DB, and if the row is there based on the primary key (url) - then call an update, if not call an insert. the function get_data is used to search the db for the row and then call the set_daat_update or set_insert_data. Appreciate the help!

myspider.py -

```
import scrapy
    import json
    import sys
    from ..items import AmazonItem


class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'price_monitor'
    newlist = []
    start_urls = []
    itemdatalist = []
    with open('C:\\Users\\Documents\\python_virtual\\price_monitor\\price_monitor\\products.json') as f:
        data = json.load(f)

        itemdatalist = data['itemdata']
#        print(type(data['itemdata']))


        for item in itemdatalist:
            start_urls.append(item['url'])

    def start_requests(self):

        for item in MySpider.start_urls:


            yield scrapy.Request(url=item, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        for url in MySpider.start_urls:
            scrapeitem = AmazonItem()

            title = response.css('span#productTitle::text').extract_first()
            title = title.strip()
            price = response.css('span#priceblock_ourprice::text').extract_first()

            scrapeitem['title'] = title
            scrapeitem['price'] = price

        for item in MySpider.data['itemdata']:
            url = item['url']
            name = item['name']
            email = item['email']

            scrapeitem['url'] = url
            scrapeitem['name'] = name
            scrapeitem['email'] = email


            yield scrapeitem
```

pipelines.py

```
import sqlite3

class PriceMonitorPipeline(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.create_connection()
        self.create_table()

    def create_connection(self):
        self.conn = sqlite3.connect("price_monitor.db")
        self.curr = self.conn.cursor()

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        self.get_data(item)
        return item

    def get_data(self, item):
        """ Check if the row already exists for this url """

        new_price = ''
        self.curr.execute("""select url, new_price from price_monitor WHERE url=url""",
                          {'url': item['url']})

        rows = self.curr.fetchone()
        print("Printing rows")
        print(rows)
        rows_url = rows[0]
        print("Rows url")
        print(rows_url)
        new_price = rows[1]
        #

        for item['url'] in rows_url:
            if item['url'] == rows_url:
                print("calling db func")

                self.set_data_update(item, rows_url, new_price)
        else:
            print("DB Calling Insert")
            self.set_insert_data(item)

    def set_insert_data(self, item):

        self.curr.execute(""" insert into price_monitor values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)""", (

            item['url'],
            item['title'],
            item['name'],
            item['email'],
            item['price'],
            item['price'],
            ))
        self.conn.commit()

    def set_data_update(self, item, rows_url, new_price):

        old_price = new_price
        self.curr.execute("""update price_monitor SET old_price=?, new_price=?
                        WHERE url=?""",
                          (old_price, item['price'], rows_url))
        print("DB Update ran")
        self.conn.commit()
```

Json file from which I get the urls and the additional data -

```
{

"itemdata": [ 
    {   "url": "https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07GWKT87L/?coliid=I36XKNB8MLE3&colid=KRASGH7290D0&psc=0&ref_=lv_ov_lig_dp_it#customerReview",
        "title": "coffee_maker_black_and_decker",
        "name": "Cobi Maguire",
        "email": "cobi@noemail.com"
    },
    {   "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Hamilton-Beach-46310-Programmable-Coffee/dp/B07684BPLB/ref=sr_1_10?keywords=coffee+maker&qid=1559098604&s=home-garden&sr=1-10",
        "title": "coffee_maker_hamilton_beach",
        "name": "Ryan Murphy",
        "email": "ryan@noemail.com"
    }

    ]

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `response.meta`:

```
class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'price_monitor'

    def start_requests(self):
        with open('C:\\Users\\Documents\\python_virtual\\price_monitor\\price_monitor\\products.json') as f:
            data = json.load(f)

            itemdatalist = data['itemdata']
            for item in itemdatalist:
                yield scrapy.Request(url=item['url'], callback=self.parse, meta={'item': item})

    def parse(self, response):

        item = response.meta["item"]
        scrapeitem = AmazonItem()

        title = response.css('span#productTitle::text').extract_first()
        title = title.strip()
        price = response.css('span#priceblock_ourprice::text').extract_first()

        scrapeitem['title'] = title
        scrapeitem['price'] = price

        scrapeitem['name'] = item["name"] # from response.meta
        scrapeitem['email'] = item["email"] # from response.meta

        yield scrapeitem
```

Comment: Thanks. That has set me on the right track to get over that issue. Now for some reason the db update functions dont seem to fire. I can see the print from inside get data, but cannot see the rows returned. Also I see an error saying KeyError: 'url' The full output is too long to post here.

Comment: I have updated with the new error - would you mind taking a look?